# Use template literals with conditional logic in hasura GQL mutation

Tags: javascript, hasura, gql

I have a gql mutatation for hasura that both inserts and updates based on whether the $vendorLicenseId has been passed to id like so:

```
export const UPDATE_LICENSE = gql`
      mutation UpdateLicense(
        $vendorId: Int!
        $licenseId: Int!
        $vendorLicenseId: Int
      ) {
        insert_license_one(
          object: {
            id: $vendorLicenseId:  
            vendor_id: $vendorId
            license_id: $licenseId
          }
          on_conflict: {
            constraint: license_pkey
            update_columns: [
              license_number
              license_id
        ]
      }
    ) {
      id
      license_id
      vendor_id
      license_number
    }
  }
    `;
```

The problem is, it's non nullable and if I just leave it like the rest of the variables, like above and don't pass the vendorLicenseId, it passes to hasura as null (obviously) and fails:

Is there a way to check in the mutation for the variable to exist and if it doesn't just omit the entire line?

something like this:

```
export const UPDATE_LICENSE = gql`
      mutation UpdateLicense(
        $vendorId: Int!
        $licenseId: Int!
        $vendorLicenseId: Int
      ) {
        insert_license_one(
          object: {
            ${ $vendorLicenseId ? `id: $vendorLicenseId`: ``}  
            vendor_id: $vendorId
            license_id: $licenseId
          }
          on_conflict: {
            constraint: license_pkey
            update_columns: [
              license_number
              license_id
        ]
      }
    ) {
      id
      license_id
      vendor_id
      license_number
    }
  }
    `;
```

I've tried variations of this and  can't get it to work. Is there a right way or better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried constructing the query string as a regular const string variable before you pass it into `gql` helper function?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix this.

Instead of trying to insert logic inside the string with template literals, I instead intercepted the variables earlier, added in conditions, and then passed the entire object.

So in my API definition:

```
 export const updateLicense = async ({
    userId,
    licenseId,
    vendorLicenseId
    dispatch,
    getState,
  }: licenseUpdateParams & BaseAPIRequest) => {
    const licenseVars: any = {
      user_id: userId,
      license_id: licenseId,
    };
    // it's non-nullable in hasura, but we need to omit it for insert so only pass it in if exists
    if (licenseId) licenseVars.id = vendorLicenseId;
    return await SIGraphQL.graphqlRequest({
      gql: UPDATE_LICENSE,
      variables: {
        licenseVars,
      },
      getState,
      dispatch,
    });
  };


export const UPDATE_LICENSE = gql`
  mutation UpdateLicense( $licenseVars: license_insert_input!) {
    insert_license_one(
     object: $licenseVars
      on_conflict: {
        constraint: license_pkey
        update_columns: [
          license_number
          license_id
    ]
  }
) {
  id
  license_id
  user_id
  license_number
}
```

}
`;